# Callback never called in child_process.exec with redis

Tags: node.js, process, redis

I am trying to start `redis` from node using the `child_process` module with the following code:

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');

childProcess.exec('redis-server --port 6380', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log(err, stdout, stderr);
})
```

When I run it, the callback is never called. I can see that my `redis-server` has started on port 6380 using `ps auwx | grep redis-server` so I don't get why this callback is not called.

Note that when I run `redis-server --port 6380` in my terminal, redis starts just fine as well.

I've tried this with `memcached` instead and it works fine.

What is the reason why this callback is not called?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the callback is called only when the process terminates.

If you need to check whether the redis process has finished initializing you can use [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) with event handlers for stdout.